# How to flatten Nested Excel data using Panda or Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, pyspark

I have below excel data, that I want to convert into an expected flat format mentioned below. In the expected format I do not want to include aggregated column such as Difference and Total. Please help me to get it done using python Pandas Dataframe or Pyspark Dataframe.

**Input Data in Excel is:**

[image]

**Expected final Format is**

[image]

df is my Pandas Dataframe over input data. Below is the output of

```
df = pd.read_excel("D:/StackOverflow.xlsx",sheet_name = 'Input')
        Data    Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6
    0   Type    Domestic    NaN NaN International   NaN NaN
    1   Unit/Subunit    Jan Feb Diff    Jan Feb Diff
    2   NaN 2020    2021    NaN 2020    2021    NaN
    3   Unit1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    4   SubUnit11   100 130 30  5000    8000    3000
    5   SubUnit12   50  80  30  1000    4000    3000
    6   SubUnit13   1000    1100    100 100000  100010  10
    7   Total Unit1 1150    1310    160 106000  112010  6010
    8   Unit2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    9   SubUnit21   1100    1130    30  15000   81100   66100
    10  SubUnit22   150 180 30  11000   42000   31000
    11  SubUnit23   11000   1110    -9890   1001000 1022010 21010
    12  Total Unit2 12250   2420    -9830   1027000 1145110 118110

print (df.index.tolist()[:3])
[0, 1, 2]

print (df.columns.tolist()[:3])
['Data', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2']

print (df.head(10).to_dict())

{'Data': {0: 'Type', 1: 'Unit/Subunit', 2: nan, 3: 'Unit1', 4: 'SubUnit11', 5: 'SubUnit12', 6: 'SubUnit13', 7: 'Total Unit1', 8: 'Unit2', 9: 'SubUnit21'}, 'Unnamed: 1': {0: 'Domestic ', 1: 'Jan', 2: 2020, 3: nan, 4: 100, 5: 50, 6: 1000, 7: 1150, 8: nan, 9: 1100}, 'Unnamed: 2': {0: nan, 1: 'Feb', 2: 2021, 3: nan, 4: 130, 5: 80, 6: 1100, 7: 1310, 8: nan, 9: 1130}, 'Unnamed: 3': {0: nan, 1: 'Diff', 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 30, 5: 30, 6: 100, 7: 160, 8: nan, 9: 30}, 'Unnamed: 4': {0: 'International', 1: 'Jan', 2: 2020, 3: nan, 4: 5000, 5: 1000, 6: 100000, 7: 106000, 8: nan, 9: 15000}, 'Unnamed: 5': {0: nan, 1: 'Feb', 2: 2021, 3: nan, 4: 8000, 5: 4000, 6: 100010, 7: 112010, 8: nan, 9: 81100}, 'Unnamed: 6': {0: nan, 1: 'Diff', 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: 3000, 5: 3000, 6: 10, 7: 6010, 8: nan, 9: 66100}}


df1 = pd.read_excel("D:/StackOverflow.xlsx",sheet_name = 'Input',header = [1,2,3])

    Type    Domestic    International
Unit/Subunit    Jan Feb Diff    Jan Feb Diff
Unnamed: 0_level_2  2020    2021    Unnamed: 3_level_2  2020    2021    Unnamed: 6_level_2
0   Unit1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   SubUnit11   100.0   130.0   30.0    5000.0  8000.0  3000.0
2   SubUnit12   50.0    80.0    30.0    1000.0  4000.0  3000.0
3   SubUnit13   1000.0  1100.0  100.0   100000.0    100010.0    10.0
4   Total Unit1 1150.0  1310.0  160.0   106000.0    112010.0    6010.0
5   Unit2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   SubUnit21   1100.0  1130.0  30.0    15000.0 81100.0 66100.0
7   SubUnit22   150.0   180.0   30.0    11000.0 42000.0 31000.0
8   SubUnit23   11000.0 1110.0  -9890.0 1001000.0   1022010.0   21010.0
9   Total Unit2 12250.0 2420.0  -9830.0 1027000.0   1145110.0   118110.0
```

Comment: What is `print (df.index.tolist()[:3])` and `print (df.columns.tolist()[:3])` ?

Comment: What is `print (df.head(10).to_dict())` ? If problem create DataFrame is possible share sample excel file?

Comment: @jezrael I am able to create Pandas Dataframe over this data but not finding a way to convert into Flat using generic way since Year and Month might be changed with data set..  I am trying to attach Excel data with it.

Comment: Super, can you share `print (df.head(10).to_dict())` ?

Comment: Because this structure is very hard create and is possible your should be different. So the best working with your data.

Comment: @jezrael Sorry I am not able to attach this data. It is not providing me anyway for that. I have updated output of print (df.head(10).to_dict()) if it will help then let me know.

Comment: @jezrael I have updated all output.

Comment: Thank you, one thing, is possible use `df1 = pd.read_excel("D:/StackOverflow.xlsx",sheet_name = 'Input',header = [1,2,3], index_col=[0])` ? And then `print (df1.to_dict())` for see how looks MultiIndex ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228933/discussion-between-nikk-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape and then remove unnecessary rows:

```
d ={('Domestic ', 'Jan', 2020): {'SubUnit11': 100.0, 'SubUnit12': 50.0, 'SubUnit13': 1000.0, 'Total Unit1': 1150.0, 'Unit2': np.nan, 'SubUnit21': 1100.0, 'SubUnit22': 150.0, 'SubUnit23': 11000.0, 'Total Unit2': 12250.0}, ('Domestic ', 'Feb', 2021): {'SubUnit11': 130.0, 'SubUnit12': 80.0, 'SubUnit13': 1100.0, 'Total Unit1': 1310.0, 'Unit2': np.nan, 'SubUnit21': 1130.0, 'SubUnit22': 180.0, 'SubUnit23': 1110.0, 'Total Unit2': 2420.0}, ('Domestic ', 'Diff', 'Unnamed: 3_level_2'):
{'SubUnit11': 30.0, 'SubUnit12': 30.0, 'SubUnit13': 100.0, 'Total Unit1': 160.0, 'Unit2': np.nan, 'SubUnit21': 30.0, 'SubUnit22': 30.0, 'SubUnit23': -9890.0, 'Total Unit2': -9830.0}, ('International', 'Jan', 2020): {'SubUnit11': 5000.0, 'SubUnit12': 1000.0, 'SubUnit13': 100000.0, 'Total Unit1': 106000.0, 'Unit2': np.nan, 'SubUnit21': 15000.0, 'SubUnit22': 11000.0, 'SubUnit23': 1001000.0, 'Total Unit2': 1027000.0},
('International', 'Feb', 2021): {'SubUnit11': 8000.0, 'SubUnit12': 4000.0, 'SubUnit13': 100010.0, 'Total Unit1': 112010.0, 'Unit2': np.nan, 'SubUnit21': 81100.0, 'SubUnit22': 42000.0, 'SubUnit23': 1022010.0, 'Total Unit2': 1145110.0}, ('International', 'Diff', 'Unnamed: 6_level_2'): {'SubUnit11': 3000.0, 'SubUnit12': 3000.0, 'SubUnit13': 10.0, 'Total Unit1': 6010.0, 'Unit2': np.nan, 'SubUnit21': 66100.0, 'SubUnit22': 31000.0, 'SubUnit23': 21010.0, 'Total Unit2': 118110.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#added missing Unit1 in sample data
df.loc['Unit1'] = np.nan
df = df.loc[df.index[-1:].tolist() + df.index[:-1].tolist()]
# print (df)
```

---

```
#create new column Unit by index with repalce non matched Unit to NaNs
df['Unit'] = df.index.where(df.index.str.startswith('Unit'))
#forward flling NaNs
df['Unit'] = df['Unit'].ffill()

#add column to index and change order of levels in MultiIndex
df = df.set_index('Unit', append=True).swaplevel(1,0)

#reshape
df = df.stack([1, 2]).rename_axis(['Unit','SubUnit','Month','Year']).reset_index()

#remove unnecessary rows
df = df[df['Month'].ne('Diff') &
        ~df['Year'].str.startswith('Unnamed', na=False) &
        ~df['SubUnit'].str.startswith(('Total', 'Unit'), na=False)]
```

---

```
print (df)
     Unit    SubUnit Month  Year  Domestic   International
2   Unit1  SubUnit11   Feb  2021      130.0         8000.0
3   Unit1  SubUnit11   Jan  2020      100.0         5000.0
6   Unit1  SubUnit12   Feb  2021       80.0         4000.0
7   Unit1  SubUnit12   Jan  2020       50.0         1000.0
10  Unit1  SubUnit13   Feb  2021     1100.0       100010.0
11  Unit1  SubUnit13   Jan  2020     1000.0       100000.0
18  Unit2  SubUnit21   Feb  2021     1130.0        81100.0
19  Unit2  SubUnit21   Jan  2020     1100.0        15000.0
22  Unit2  SubUnit22   Feb  2021      180.0        42000.0
23  Unit2  SubUnit22   Jan  2020      150.0        11000.0
26  Unit2  SubUnit23   Feb  2021     1110.0      1022010.0
27  Unit2  SubUnit23   Jan  2020    11000.0      1001000.0
```

Last is add datetime column for sorting:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'] + df['Year'].astype(str), format='%b%Y')

df = df.sort_values(['Unit','SubUnit','Date'], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
     Unit    SubUnit Month  Year  Domestic   International       Date
0   Unit1  SubUnit11   Jan  2020      100.0         5000.0 2020-01-01
1   Unit1  SubUnit11   Feb  2021      130.0         8000.0 2021-02-01
2   Unit1  SubUnit12   Jan  2020       50.0         1000.0 2020-01-01
3   Unit1  SubUnit12   Feb  2021       80.0         4000.0 2021-02-01
4   Unit1  SubUnit13   Jan  2020     1000.0       100000.0 2020-01-01
5   Unit1  SubUnit13   Feb  2021     1100.0       100010.0 2021-02-01
6   Unit2  SubUnit21   Jan  2020     1100.0        15000.0 2020-01-01
7   Unit2  SubUnit21   Feb  2021     1130.0        81100.0 2021-02-01
8   Unit2  SubUnit22   Jan  2020      150.0        11000.0 2020-01-01
9   Unit2  SubUnit22   Feb  2021      180.0        42000.0 2021-02-01
10  Unit2  SubUnit23   Jan  2020    11000.0      1001000.0 2020-01-01
11  Unit2  SubUnit23   Feb  2021     1110.0      1022010.0 2021-02-01
```